# SQLAlchemy: method '_connection_for_bind()' is already in progress

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I recently updated SQLAlchemy (with [asyncio] package) to `1.4.46` and started to get the following exception when committing:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IllegalStateChangeError: Method 'commit()' can't be called here; method '_connection_for_bind()' is already in progress and this would cause an unexpected state change to <SessionTransactionState.CLOSED: 5>

Before updating to the new version, it was working fine.

```py
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from sqlalchemy import exc, event, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession as SQLAlchemyAsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool, Pool
from contextvars import ContextVar
from sanic import Sanic
import asyncio


class EngineNotInitialisedError(Exception):
    pass


class DBSessionContext:
    def __init__(self, session: Session, commit_on_exit: bool = True) -> None:
        self.session = session
        self._query = None
        self.commit_on_exit = commit_on_exit
        self.token = None

    async def close(self, exc_type=None, exc_value=None, traceback=None):
        if self._query:
            if exc_value and getattr(exc_value, 'status_code', 500) > 300:
                await self._query.rollback()
                self._post_processing.clear()
            else:
                await self._query.commit()
                await self.run_post_processing()

            await self._query.close()

        if self._post_processing:
            await self.run_post_processing()

    def set_token(self, token):
        self.token = token

    @property
    def query(self) -> Session:
        if not self._query:
            self._query = self.session()

        return self._query


class AsyncSession(SQLAlchemyAsyncSession):
    async def execute(self, statement, **parameters):
        try:
            if isinstance(statement, str):
                # We wrap around the `text()` method automatically
                statement = text(statement)
            return await super().execute(statement, parameters)
        except exc.OperationalError as e:
            if e.orig.args[0] == 1205:
                # Lock wait timeout exceeded
                await self.rollback()
                return await super().execute(statement, parameters)

            raise e


class DBSession:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = None
        self.session = None
        self._session = None
        self.context = ContextVar("context", default=None)

    def init_app(self, app: Sanic, url: str, commit_on_exit: bool = True) -> None:
        self.commit_on_exit = commit_on_exit

        engine_args = {
            'echo': app.config.get('DATABASE_ECHO', cast=bool, default=False),
            'echo_pool': app.config.get('DATABASE_ECHO_POOL', cast=bool, default=False),
            'poolclass': NullPool,  # will be used to create a connection pool instance using the connection parameters given in the URL
            # if pool_class is not NullPool:

            # the number of connections to allow in connection pool “overflow”
            # 'max_overflow': app.config.get('DATABASE_MAX_OVERFLOW', cast=int, default=10),
            # if True will enable the connection pool “pre-ping” feature that tests connections for liveness upon each checkout
            # 'pool_pre_ping': app.config.get('DATABASE_POOL_PRE_PING', cast=bool, default=True),
            # the number of connections to keep open inside the connection pool
            # 'pool_size': app.config.get('DATABASE_POOL_SIZE', cast=int, default=5),
            # this setting causes the pool to recycle connections after the given number of seconds has passed
            # 'pool_recycle': app.config.get('DATABASE_POOL_RECYCLE', cast=int, default=-1),
            # number of seconds to wait before giving up on getting a connection from the pool
            # 'pool_timeout': app.config.get('DATABASE_POOL_TIMEOUT', cast=int, default=3600),
        }

        self.engine = create_async_engine(
            url,
            **engine_args
        )

        self.session = sessionmaker(
            bind=self.engine,
            expire_on_commit=False,
            class_=AsyncSession,
            autoflush=False
        )

    async def __aenter__(self):
        if not isinstance(self.engine, AsyncEngine):
            raise EngineNotInitialisedError

        session_ctx = DBSessionContext(self.session, self.commit_on_exit)
        session_ctx.set_token(self.context.set(session_ctx))

        return session_ctx

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        session_ctx = self.context.get()
        await asyncio.shield(session_ctx.close(exc_type, exc_value, traceback))

        self.context.reset(session_ctx.token)

    @property
    def query(self) -> Session:
        return self.context.get().query


@event.listens_for(Pool, "checkout")
def check_connection(dbapi_con, con_record, con_proxy):
    '''Listener for Pool checkout events that pings every connection before using.
    Implements pessimistic disconnect handling strategy. See also:
    http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic'''

    cursor = dbapi_con.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT 1")
    except exc.OperationalError as ex:
        if ex.args[0] in (2006,   # MySQL server has gone away
                          2013,   # Lost connection to MySQL server during query
                          2055):  # Lost connection to MySQL server at '%s', system error: %d
            raise exc.DisconnectionError()  # caught by pool, which will retry with a new connection
        else:
            raise

    cursor.close()


db = DBSession()
```

The code is called with the following :

```
async with db:
    await db.query.execute('INSERT INTO ...')
```

What is causing the InvalidStateChangeError I'm having? How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the issue was related to calling `asyncio.gather` on two functions that call the database. I'll write an answer for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a discussion on the Github repository of SQLAlchemy, that gives a reason why the issue is occurring:
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9312

The suggestion is that the code is calling something like

`asyncio.gather(func(session), func2(session)` with the two function sharing the same session, which causes the `sqlalchemy.exc.IllegalStateChangeError`

Removing the `asyncio.gather` call resolve the issue. (Or use two sessions, one for each functions).

Comment: Thanks for posting the GH issue. I got around this by moving the execution of func1 and func2 down into a task that setup connection and session for each gathered task